# Android navigation drawer inflation error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error when I create navigation drawer activity and set as launcher activity.  due to this app is crashing.  I have added both 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' and 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1' in app build.gradle file.

My build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sampleapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

Error:

```
08-24 20:38:01.673  15555-15555/sampleapp.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sampleapp.app/sampleapp.app.MenuSliderActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment**
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment**
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at sampleapp.app.MenuSliderActivity.onCreate(MenuSliderActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sampleapp.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:100)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:668)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at sampleapp.app.MenuSliderActivity.onCreate(MenuSliderActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the xml file with the options ?

Comment: Try to change buildToolsVersion  to "22.2.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the new support design library NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item_color_selector"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
```

Comment: @abinaya glad to hear! Would be cool if you mark the answer as right :)